# Running Cucumber tests on headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, cucumber

I am interested in running our acceptance tests with Cucumber. Is there any way to run them on Chrome's headless mode?

Comment: Works on the latest chrome version on linux or mac only. Take a look at this https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/. Guessing here - If you are able to connect using selenium, cucumberjs should work the normal way

Answer (score 2):

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver'
import test from 'selenium-webdriver/testing'

test.describe('Test', () => {
  test.it('with headless chrome.', () => {
    const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
    **chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', {
      'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']
    });**
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
      **.withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)**
      .build();

    driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
    driver.quit();
  })
})
```

try those args ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']